# Stored Procedure is not creating ##temp_merchant

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am new to stack and MSSQL. I have created a stored procedure and there I am trying to create global temp table but it's not able to create any temp table `##temp_merchant` in `tempdb`.

How ever I have tried to execute Stored procedure with select statement, it works fine and return the data.

Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Error:

```
Merchant::get, SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields.
```

MSSQL Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetMerchantById 
    @merchantId nvarchar(50)
AS
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temp_merchant') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tempdb..##temp_merchant WHERE merchant_id = @merchantId))
        BEGIN
               IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ##temp_merchant WHERE merchant_id = @merchantId))
               INSERT INTO ##temp_merchant
               SELECT
                    merchant.merchant_id as merchant_id                 
                    ,COALESCE(orders.order_id, 0) as order_id                   
                    ,COALESCE(merchant.name, '') as name 
                    ,COALESCE(merchant.address1, '') as address1 
                    ,COALESCE(merchant.address2, '') as address2 
                    ,COALESCE(merchant.city, '') as city 
                    ,COALESCE(merchant.state, '') as state 
                    ,COALESCE(merchant.zipcode, '') as zipcode 
                    ,merchant.active as active
                    ,COALESCE(merchant.network_id, '') as network_id                    
                    ,COALESCE(provider.feature_set, '') as provider_feature_set                     
                FROM abc_merchant merchant 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_provider provider ON merchant.provider_id = provider.provider_id 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_gatenetwork network ON provider.network_id = gatenetwork.network_id 
          END  
            
      ELSE
          BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM ##temp_merchant WHERE merchant_id = @merchantId         
          END
    END  
  ELSE
    BEGIN 
    CREATE TABLE ##temp_merchant 
    (
        merchant_id BIGINT, 
        provider_id int, 
        network_id int,
        name nvarchar(100),
        address1 nvarchar(100),
        address2 nvarchar(100),
        city nvarchar(50),
        state nchar(2),
        zipcode nvarchar(10),
        active smallint,
        provider_feature_set nvarchar(512),     
    )
    
    INSERT INTO ##temp_merchant
    SELECT
        merchant.merchant_id as merchant_id                 
        ,COALESCE(orders.order_id, 0) as order_id                   
        ,COALESCE(merchant.name, '') as name 
        ,COALESCE(merchant.address1, '') as address1 
        ,COALESCE(merchant.address2, '') as address2 
        ,COALESCE(merchant.city, '') as city 
        ,COALESCE(merchant.state, '') as state 
        ,COALESCE(merchant.zipcode, '') as zipcode 
        ,merchant.active as active
        ,COALESCE(merchant.network_id, '') as network_id                    
        ,COALESCE(provider.feature_set, '') as provider_feature_set                     
    FROM abc_merchant merchant 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_provider provider ON merchant.provider_id = provider.provider_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_gatenetwork network ON provider.network_id = gatenetwork.network_id 

    SELECT * FROM ##temp_merchant WHERE merchant_id = @merchantId         
    
    END
```

PHP Code:

```
$data = array(':merchant_id' => $merchant_id );
$sql = "{ CALL dbo.GetMerchantById(:merchant_id) }";



      try {
            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);                             
            $result = $this->executeQuery($stmt, $data, 'Merchant::get');

            if ($result) {
                $result = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
        }
        catch(\PDOException $e) {
            $result = false;
            error_log('Merchant::get, ' . $e->getMessage(), 0);
        }
```

Comment: Unless you are creating `##temp_merchant` in a batch prior to `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temp_merchant') IS NOT NULL`, and that other batch doesn't terminate before the `IF` is called, it is *always* going be false. I see nothing that creates said table in your `CALL`, so the temporary table likely won't exist. What are you trying to achieve with said temporary table?

Comment: @Larnu I am trying to optimise query overhead instead retrieving data from tables via joins, it can be stored in temp table and then retrieved quickly.

Comment: But as soon as the batch ends, which is the one you create the **temporary** table in (emphases, **temporary**) it is dropped. Your procedure effectively `INSERT`s a bunch of rows into a *temporary* table, and then disposes of it. It's a fruitless task. As the name suggests, a temporary table is *temporary*; it only exists for as long as the batch that created it does.

Comment: @Larnu Is there a way that can helps to achieve the job?

Comment: We're missing something here; you haven't answered the question of what the temporary table is for. You don't *use* the data it, just `INSERT` into it (and then implicitly `DROP` is immediately afterwards)... it's like writing a essay, and then going to your file managed and pressing `Shift`+`Del` on it immediately after you've finished.

Comment: I used the data to get the merchant using temp table, that's why I am trying to create, store and fetch data from temp table. Please help If I am missing something here.

Comment: *"fetch data from temp table"* but you *aren't* fetching said data; that is my point.

Comment: @Larnu I have updated the question stored procedure to answer your question(After creating temp table retrieve data).

Comment: I don't see the need to `INSERT` all the data, which isn't filtered, into the temporary table to then just `SELECT` data for a single value of `merchant_id`. Seems you should just `SELECT` the data in the first place.

Comment: @Larnu Well this is for performance enhancement of API. As per my understanding once I have inserted the data into temp table then with next request it just pull the data from temp table. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: What next request? Again, I think you're missing the first word in the name **temporary** table; it is **TEMPORARY**. It isn't persistent, it exists for a short (temporary) amount of time, and in this case that's until the batch (procedure) completes. It's no good `INSERT`ing data into a temporary table for "use later" if that "later" is after the table is dropped...

Comment: If you follow through the logic of the `IF`s `ELSE`s and `BEGIN` `END`s, you will see that in some branches you are not selecting the data. I note also that you have `INSERT INTO #temp_merchant` rather than `INSERT INTO ##temp_merchant` And I'm sure bandying around words like "temp table" and "performance" make you feel better, but it's unlikely it's actually doing anything useful. Just do a normal `SELECT` without any temp tables